# Ajax during javascript window.beforeunload: returning error

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

I need to perform an ajax request to send some data server-side every time the user decides to leave the page. However I do not wish to disrupt them in leaving: I do not want popup messages to show up. Currently my code is thus:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
   unloadAjax();
}
```

This does not work and causes a momentary ajax-error message to show up. However, if I add a `return false;` statement inside the onbeforeunload function, the ajax works fine. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `return false`, a confirmation dialog shows up, delaying the page unload. Meanwhile, the AJAX request finishes. When no `return` statement is included, the page will immediately unloads, terminating all active connections (and breaking your AJAX request).

Comment: I got that part, but still don't know how to delay unload just enough for ajax to finish

Comment: If your request doesn't take long, use a synchronous AJAX request. You should however be careful to use this method. It's not user-friendly to freeze the browser for, say, 1 second, just because you want to notify the server. It's better to use `return "Something not saved"` through `beforeunload`if your webpage is clearly an editor (including data which must be saved).